# Bulk API with PK-Chunking creates huge sets of batches when query is with where clause and subset of the records needs to be extracted

Tags: rest-api, bulk-api

We have a Java API which uses Bulk API to extract records from an Object. The "select query" has  a where clause, which should extract a subset of records, to honour the where clause, but we see that huge numer of batches are created on the Salesforce Server side, and many a times, the BULK API limits are hit

For example :

Number of records in the Object Account : 20000 
We enable the connection and set the Pk Chunking header as , with chunk size as 2000

```
bulkConnection.addHeader("Sforce-Enable-PKChunking","chunkSize=2000");
```

Select Query :

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate >= 2018-07-20T05:00:00.000Z"
```

As per the query to match the condition, the query should return only 10 records (at most 1 batch), but we see that there are 10 batches created on the Salesforce Server.

Why is there 10 batches that are created, when the number of records to be extracted is only 10 which can fit in 1 batch.

Is there any setting that can be applied, or code tuning that can be done so that only 1 batch is created on the Salesforce Server

Answer (score 3):

Using a chunk size of 2000 will automatically add a filter on `Id` to your `WHERE` clause such that there are 2000 rows in each batch before any other filters in your `WHERE` clause are applied.

If you had 10,000 total Accounts in your org, using a chunk size of 2000 will result in five batches being created even if four of those batches will contain no results because of your filter on `CreatedDate`.